# SSL Error while sending /https request to parse.com

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, jmeter, ssl-certificate, load-testing

i m trying to perform load testing on "https://tickleb.parseapp.com" using jmeter.
but every time m getting the errors

Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Response headers:
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Please  provide me tips to achieve the solution.
thanks.

Comment: What versions of Jmeter and Java are you using. Can you also show your test plan zooming on HTTP Request ?

Comment: What about other questions ?